# Unable to turn on speaker phone in call Android

Tags: android, call, android-audiomanager, speakerphone

I am developing a Phone application I want to turn speaker ON/OFF in call.
I want to enable and disable the speaker with a button click and I am using the following code.
I tried different methods to turn on speakerphone but those are not worked.

```
     AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? you have addded the required permissions right?

Comment: i didn't get any error.                                                                                                                       
and added below permissions in manifest     
MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, 
RECORD_AUDIO,   
MODIFY_PHONE_STATE